# query or datagridview dependant on 7 combo boxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I'm creating an application in vb.net and in that there are 7 combo boxes, What I want to do is create a query or fill datagridview according to selected combo boxes

for example if I select one combo box, the datagridview should reflect the data according to that one combo box, or If I select any 2,4 or all of them the datagridview should reflect the selection. The order of the combo box is random.

Can anybody help me with the logic?  here's the UI looks like
[image]

Any combo box from these seven combo boxes can be selected in random manner or even all of them can be selected. I want to build a query that will consider this random nature of the combo boxes.

Suppose I select first combo box and press Filter button(first from left), then DGV should be filtered according to that, now If i select next combobox say 3rd then DGV should be filtered considering both the combo boxes, and so on. The second button resets the selection.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more setup info. Also, what have you tried so far that isn't working? And be quite specific when asking us a question so that we can actually help you.

Comment: do it in db query and then set it as your dgv's datasources

Comment: Updated the question. Did you get the Idea of what I'm trying to say??

Comment: Build a composite query depending on the combobox values.

Comment: As @RawN said, build your query on existing `ComboBox` values.  As a new value is selected, the query builder will add it to the query filters.  Once you click your `reset button`, clear the selected value from each `ComboBox` and perform your most basic query (i.e. `select * from table where 1 = 1`).

Comment: Are you using a bound or unbound datagrid? If it is bound, look into populating a `WHERE CLAUSE` dynamically and filtering the binding source.